# Using Kant's Categorical Imperative, would it be ethical for tour agencies to organise tours to countries with poor human rights records?

Tags: ethics, kant, deontology

An example would be Myanmar. Aung Suu Kyi previously urged travelers to boycott Myanmar to deny the military junta of income.

Comment: Welcome to Phil.SE! Good question...

Comment: The mediate consequences are normally excluded from moral responsibility by Kant, see *Metaphysics of Morals*, Ak. 6:227-8

Answer (score 2):

I'd say, yes, it would. If the maxim of this action were turned into a universal law — that is, if everybody started doing tours of countries with poor human rights records — the human rights records of those countries would likely improve.